# Массивы в Паскале

Tags: delphi

Как найти максимальное среди чисел в массиве которые не повторяются? Извинеите за столь глупый вопрос, я начинающий) Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Заведите переменную, которая будет хранить наибольшее прочитанное до сих пор число.

Answer (score 2):

На выбор варианты, полезно реализовать оба и сравнить какой будет быстрее, массивы при этом брать размером побольше:

1. бежите по массиву как только встретили максимальное число, пробегаете по массиву проверяете чтоб не было повтора. если повторы есть, ищите следующий максимум. т.е. цикл в цикле.
2. сортируете массив, затем идете с конца отсортированного массива и проверяете какое первое из чисел не будет повторяться.